# How do I make pretty "tag"s in-question?

Tags: support, tags, formatting

I know about using backticks to make `code blocks`, but how do I get pretty, clickable tag-things in questions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write `[tag:tagname]`.

Renders as: [tagname](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/tagname).

For tags from the Meta site, use `[meta-tag:tagname]` instead.

Comment: Thanks (sorry for the small question). (I have to wait 3m to accept answer!)